# Laravel: convert input text into date to validate with "after"

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to get a datetime from a form:

```
{!! Form::text('somedate', null, array('class' => 'datetimepicker', 'id' => 'somedate')) !!}
```

Datetimepicker plugin expects a text input type to works. If I change it to a date input type, the plugin do not work.

So, on my controller, I'm doing some validations:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [                 
  'somedate' => 'required|after:tomorrow',
```

This is not working because "after" validation expects a date input type. How can I convert my text field to a date on my controller before it gets validate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `date` rule to those rules before the `after` rule.

```
'somedate' => 'required|date|after:tomorrow'
```

You can also use the `date_format` rule instead of `date` if you need to use a specific format.

[Laravel 5.2 - Validation - Rule After](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-after)

Comment: I changed to 'required|date|after:tomorrow', but it still not validating my date. Maybe my datetime input format is interfering on in. I'm using dd/mm/YYYY. Should I convert it on my controller before validate?

Comment: you might need to alter the format that is being sent in the post, or perhaps trying the `date_format` rule instead of `date`.

Comment: I change it to 'required|date_format:"dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii"|after:now', but when I choose 13/01/2016 11:10, the validation says that my input is not in dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii format.

Comment: I got it. I'm using 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y H:i"|after:now' and it's working pretty well.